# How to login with one ID/Pass from one computer at a time only

Tags: php, mysql, security, authentication

I have a PHP website with signup/login system. For security reasons, I want that the users are only able to sign in from one PC at a time. If same ID/Password tries to sign in from another PC while a user is already logged in with that ID/Password, it should generate an error message.

Please tell me how it is possible and what is the best way to do it?

I am using only cookies...

```
<?php function sec_session_start() {
        $session_name = 'sec_session_id'; // Set a custom session name
        $secure = false; // Set to true if using https.
        $httponly = true; // This stops javascript being able to access the session id. 

        ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); // Forces sessions to only use cookies. 
        $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); // Gets current cookies params.
        session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly); 
        session_name($session_name); // Sets the session name to the one set above.
        session_start(); // Start the php session
        session_regenerate_id(true); // regenerated the session, delete the old one. 
}
```

Here is the code:

```
if(login($name, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
            // Login success
            if($name == 'admin'){
                if($signin == 'zero'){
                    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE users SET signin = 'one' WHERE name = 'admin'");
                    $stmt->execute();   
            ?>
            <span class="TextFont"><br /><br />Welcome Admin! <a href="admin.php">Click here to access your Admin Panel</a>! <br /><br /> <a href="logout.php">Logout</a></span>
            <?php }
                else{
                    echo"You are already logged in from some other system! $signin";
                }}
            else{
 // some PHP code
}
else{
 // some PHP code
}
```

Comment: add a extra row to the table, it is the user login 0 or 1 check the value each time, if it is 1 return false, else can log in

Comment: cookies are really easy to hack if you share a sample of db structure and how you log in will be easy to help

Comment: @jycr753!! I am starting a secure session upon login and using it on every page of PHP. Please have a look at my code which I have just added and let me know the loopholes. And thank you for your solution, I might implement it.

Comment: cool, but what i mean is when you make the login and compare data to your db. there you can check if the user it is log in or not.. the session it is just something with in the server and the browser

Comment: I did what you said. I inserted a value into the table when the user signs in, and i updated that value to zero when they logout. But now the problem is that when I try to log in again, it shows me undesired output (that you are already logged in). but when i press CTRL+F5 on my keyboard, it takes me into the member area and everything else work perfectly. May i know why i need to have a CTRL Refreh ??

Comment: do you remove the session and update the cookie?

Comment: please have a look at my updated code...

Comment: in the logout page i am destroying the session and setting back the value of signin to zero...

Comment: you are missing one `}` in the last `else` aslo change those strings to int, mostly for speed and easy to process .. but check that else it maybe causing the error

Comment: @jycr753!! No may be I have missed it here but in my coding it's perfectly fine. I changed to int but it is doing the same...

Answer (score 0):

if you also add a column session_id in the user table and you store sessions in a database (even more secure) You also could check more easier if user sessions are expired to update the signin column to 0 again and this is more waterproof against users that don't use a signout feature... (upgraded jycr753 solution)

Answer (score 0):

What has worked for me in the past is this.

Add a column to your user table to store the session id.

When a user authenticates update the user record with the session for login.

When you are checking to see if a request is authenticated or not search the database for the user's session id.

Note with session_regenerate_id occuring on each page you will have to update the user record with each request, an alternative would be to store a unique value within the session and have that updated on the user record and confirm an authenticated request by matching values of that.

In pseudo-code

```
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
if ($_SESSION["session_key"]);
$user = UserStore::getUserBySessionKey($_SESSION["session_key"]);
if ($user){
    // the request is authenticated
} else {
    // redirect to the login page
}
```

And on Login

```
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
$user = UserStore::authenticateUser($username, $password);
if ($user){
     $sessionKey = uniqid().$user->username;
     $user->setSessionkey($sessionKey);
     $user->save();
     $_SESSION["session_key"] = $sessionKey;
} else {
    // show the login form with an error
}
```